# Whitebox in menucontrol

Tags: asp.net, controls, menu

Im trying to use the asp.net menucontrol but sadly without any luck.
Here is what I have done.

First i created a web.sitemap
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="qaz.dk"  description="" roles="">
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Links"  description="" roles="">
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Computer"  description="" roles="">
          <siteMapNode url="as.aspx" title="Antivirus + Spyware"  description="" roles="" />
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Other"  description="" roles="">
          <siteMapNode url="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="StackOverflow"  description="" roles="" />
        </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Then I added the menucontrol to the masterpage and change some of the default values like this

```
<asp:Menu ID="MenuControl" Orientation="Horizontal" 
    runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Font-Names="Courier New" 
    ForeColor="#413D3D" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" 
    DynamicHorizontalOffset="20" StaticDisplayLevels="1"  
    StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" >
</asp:Menu>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" StartingNodeOffset="0" />
```

The result looks like this
[alt text http://foto.qaz.dk/menu.jpg](http://foto.qaz.dk/menu.jpg)

I was expecting the 'Computer' and 'Other' menu items to be displayed
The size of the whitebox depends on the number of menuitems.

When moving the mousepointer over the whitebox i doesnt expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is am using ie8, so i added the following line to the head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```